# Nhibernate ICriteria API Reference

Tags: nhibernate, icriteria

Is there any good ICriteria API overview? Chapter 12 from the official NHibernate reference is too short and I still don't have clear view of the ICriteria usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Criteria stuff in NHibernate is nearly identical to Hibernate (the Java version).  Try  broadening your search in that way.

In fact, I use [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/) as a reference.